# Google Cloud Function cannot connect to Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

We have a Google Cloud Function that tries to connect to a Redis server that sits on a Compute Engine instance. The Compute Engine Redis port is open and can connect to the Redis server from our local machines. Nonetheless, when the Cloud Function tries to do so, it gets the following error:

> Redis connection to 35.xxx.xx.xx:6379 failed - connect ETIMEDOUT 35.xxx.xx.xx:6379 at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11) at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20) at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1105:14) code: 'ETIMEDOUT', errno: 'ETIMEDOUT', syscall: 'connect', address: '35.xxx.xx.xx', port: 6379 }

We are using the ***[redis](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis)*** npm package (Redis Node Client) to connect which again works from our local machines.

We pass the IP of the EC server to the *host* value and the authentication secret to the *password* value. Again this seems to work locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Firebase project on a paid plan? Or is it on the free Spark plan?

Comment: Paid as you Go so no problem there. It could be something firewall related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all, it was indeed a firewall issue. We didn't have the correct service account setup.

One needs to visit the [firewall rules](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/details/instance-name?project=your-project-name) config page and add the appropriate Source Filter (or Second source filter) to type Service Account and add the service account of the Cloud Functions.

Comment: Good to hear that you found the cause of the problem, and thanks for self-answering. Is there any way you could update your answer to include the configuration you had to do? That type of information is extremely useful to other developers who encounter the same problem.

Comment: Please include the "Equivalent REST response" of your new rule (minus ids and other sensitive info, if you wish).

Comment: Yes please, add the REST response if you can.

Answer (score 1):

GCP has released beta version of "Serverless VPC access" to connect Compute Engine VMs from a Cloud Function using internal IPs. Follow the [tutorials here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/connecting-vpc)

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution that worked best for me. It is the preferred approach than can unblock any number of cloud functions.